# unable to have a set of images in stack panel? I have tried it in Grid also but some issues

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

i have to make a layout such that images are arranged as follows:

```
            img1 img2 img3
            img4 img5 img5
            img6 ....
```

I am using Stack Panel with horizontal orientation.But i can only see my first row.Is there a way to add more rows to it so that i can see all images.Also how to set border for each image in stack panel?
In Grid only one image is shown.I am not able to set row and column for images.Can someone suggest something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basically how StackPanel works. You could alternatively use a Grid, a Canvas or a vertical StackPanel of Horizontal StackPanels.

An overview here of how they differ and which is good when.

[Silverlight Layout System](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645025%28VS.95%29.aspx)

Comment: thanks a lot Mick.. but i guess u have forgotten to add the link!!

Comment: hehe, you were quick... it's there now ;)

Comment: i tried it using Grid but i have only one image shown or may be they have overriden each other..can u provide a sample code for grid?

Comment: you'll need to set the row and column for each image in a grid

Comment: I am new to all dis..so can u provide some code for it?How to set the row and column?

Answer (score 4):

If you were doing non-WP7 development, I'd say you want the [WrapPanel](http://jesseliberty.com/2009/01/02/silverlight-toolkit-wrappanel/) from the Silverlight Toolkit.  Set Orientation="Horizontal" and you'll have what you want.

However, I'm not sure if that works with WP7 or if there's a library for WP7 that offers that kind of panel.  You might give it a try and see what happens.

Comment: There is a WP7 specific version of the toolkti which includes a WrapPanel. http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/55034

Comment: I have downloaded this toolkit but i am unable to get the tools in my toolbox.I am using Microsoft Visual studio 2010 Express Edition for Windows Phone.Plz help